# How to change the mysql query to retrieve data (pivot view)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset as follows,

[image]

I need to get the average xdr_count of each table_name for 7 past days..So I tried as below.

```
SELECT
    t1.table_date,
    t1.table_name,
    t1.xdr_count,
    t2.AVG_XDR,
    t2.Threshold
FROM stat t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT table_name, AVG(xdr_count) AS AVG_XDR,AVG(xdr_count)*.8 as Threshold
    FROM stat
    where table_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    GROUP BY table_name
) t2
    ON t2.table_name = t1.table_name
where table_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

This works fine and I could get the output as below.

[image]

But I need to rearrange this table to a pivot view(hope this can called as pivot view) such as below.

[image]

I need to mention the table name,Avg(XDR) and dates with appropraite xdr_count values.

Can someone help me to change the view of  output result..

Note: Threshold value will be use later.

Comment: There is a lot of solutions for "How to build pivot query on MySQL" there - use search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you want to calculate the avg_xdr columns. But, you can try something like this.

```
SELECT table_name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN table_date = '2022-08-21' then avg_xdr else 0 END) AS avg_xdr,
      MAX(CASE WHEN table_date = '2022-08-21' then xdr_count else 0 END) AS '2022-08-21',
      MAX(CASE WHEN table_date = '2022-08-22' then xdr_count else 0 END) AS '2022-08-22',
      MAX(CASE WHEN table_date = '2022-08-23' then xdr_count else 0 END) AS '2022-08-23',
      MAX(CASE WHEN table_date = '2022-08-24' then xdr_count else 0 END) AS '2022-08-24'
FROM tableA
Group by table_name
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70fb299035014e3cb981146387ab7083)